# How to assign database values into global variables in a class

Tags: c#, oledb

I am creating a windows forms in C# with following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\RAV21001310\\OneDrive\\Database1.accdb;"))

            {

                connection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password", connection))

                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username.Text);

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password.Text);

                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())

                    {

                        int count = 0;

                        while (reader.Read())

                        {

                            count = count + 1;

                        }

                        if (count == 1)

                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");

                        }

                        if (count > 1)

                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password");

                        }

                        if (count == 0)

                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Username or password incorrect");

                        }

                    }

                }

                connection.Close();

            }

        }

    }


public class User

    {

        public string Username;

        public string Password;

        public string FirstName;

        public string LastName;

        public string Gender;

        public int Age;

        public int TotalPoints;

    }
```

The first part is for a login form. The part I am struggling with is how to make it so when a user logs in it gets all his relevant information like username, password, TotalPoints etc from the database in ms access and assigns it to the variables in the class so they can be called throughout different forms.

Comment: Side note, you shouldn't store passwords in a database.  Google _"password salting"_.

Comment: Try marking the User class as static so when you populate the Username/Password with values you can use them globally.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add parameters for the username and password
command.Parameters.Add("@Username").Value = username.text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Password").Value = password.text;

// Execute the query
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Validate the user's credentials
bool isValid = false;
if (reader.Read())
{
    User user = new User
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
        // Add all fileds you want to use...
    }

    isValid = true;
}

// Close the reader and the connection
reader.Close();
connection.Close();

// Do someting with result 
...
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I get the username and password from the database and pass it on to the variables for it in the class globally so it can be used on all forms.

Comment: I updated the code you could check it out

Comment: Oh thanks that helps a lot. Just one thing I'm sorry I'm just really new at C#. When I call for example the Id in a message box would the correct format be MessageBox Show("UserID is " + user[Id])

Comment: it would be corrent but using string interpolation would be much better for example MessageBox.Show($"UserId is {user[Id]}") for more info you could check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) also if my answer helped you accept it as solution